# wp7-how to make a thread navigate pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

I want to check for changes in the aplication state every time interval, and if it has changed, to open a window, and  give the user 10 seconds to press on the window, if he does press on the window, then to allow him to navigate freely in the window, and if he doesn't press, to return back to the window before. I thought to implement it with a thread running in the background and waking up every time interval I want. Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as a scenario with lots of potential issues.

How do you stop the "window" appearing at an inconvenient time to the user? (e.g. when they were just about to tap on som.ething)

Why not just raise the notification when the state actually changes? This way you wouldn't need to poll.

What is the "Window" you are displaying? How does it differ from the page it is replacing? Is this a popup or are you actually navigating to a different page?

What is the state that's changing? How is it changing without user interaction?

Can't you notify the user of the state change without a potentially intrusive display of a new "window"?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @matt-lacey, this could be dangerous and might result in a bad user experience.

With that said, this **might** work

```
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        //navigation code here
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know you could do a pop-up window, could you elaborate?
I've made a thread that is running at the background and making some work, if it decides that a change is necessary, I want to give the user a chance to react to it, or ignore it.
I'm pretty new to this, so if there is a better way than to navigate to a different page i would love to hear it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to notify the user that something has happened/changed and give them the option to do something about it, which is exactly what "toast" notifcations are all about. They pop up at the top of the screen to inform the user, and then the user can tap that toast to do something, e.g. when WiFi networks are available, you tap the toast to select an available network.

The [Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) includes the `ToastRequestTrigger` that you use to display toast notifications. The [Windows Phone Developer Guide](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/) from the patterns & practices team gives examples of using the `ToastRequestTrigger`. You will need to implement the tap handling yourself in the toast content, but this should be simple enough.